# Fixing 'A matching symbol file was not found'. Visual Studio debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Similar to [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599663/a-matching-symbol-file-was-not-found-cannot-find-open-pdb-file) but it haven't solved my issue so it's **not a duplicate**.
C:/????/WebApiProject is path to my solution folder. I *can't debug* WebApi controller because *no symbols are loaded*, project works fine.

**I tried to:**

1. Clean solution, rebuild solution, build solution.
2. Tried to delete all files in obj/debug then repeat 1.
3. Tried to create manually .pdb file with project name, inside same folder with .dll but 'A matching symbol error' will be trown or ApiProvider module will not be loaded at all.
4. Tried to debug project on other laptop with same VS version (2017).

**I can't post more than 2 links. Here are some screenshoots:**

Module path:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvSZK.png

Symbol Load information:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLvx9.png

Symbol Status:
https:// i.stack.imgur.com/lEZBe.png

Original Location:
https:// i.stack.imgur.com/l2V99.png

ApiProvider.dll location:
https:// i.stack.imgur.com/1UiXx.png

**P.S.** If you downvote this question please leave a comment with your reason, I think this will be more constructive for a junior. Thanks.