# Visual Studio debugging: cannot find pdb, A matching symbol file was not found in this folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I've combed through [a matching symbol file was not found in this folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309722/a-matching-symbol-file-was-not-found-in-this-folder) and [A matching symbol file was not found (Cannot find/open pdb file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599663/a-matching-symbol-file-was-not-found-cannot-find-open-pdb-file) but I can't get anything to work. I'm trying to debug a project that I inherited from another company. My projects compile and the site works, but I can't get the breakpoints to attach. In the project properties, Debug Info is set to full.

I went into file explorer and set the security on the root folder of my project to give full control to Everyone

I went to Debug > Windows > Modules an found my projects, and the Symbol Status for all of them is "Cannot fin or open the PDB file". On my project (MyProject.Web.dll), I right clicked > Load Symbols and browsed to ProjectFolder > Website > bin and selected the corresponding pdb, MyProject.Web.pdb. I can see it there in the folder

[image]

Comment: If you're manually picking the pdb and it's still saying it doesn't match, then your build might be doing something slightly odd. Have a look at this one, I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109575/symbol-file-not-loading-for-debugging-custom-project-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: I noticed that it in the Symbol Load Information, it's looking for the pdb under that path that the previous developer was using for his project: C:\Users\NAME-OF-PRIOR-DEV\Documents\project-name\src\Web\obj\Debug\MyProject.Web.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file. But I don't know how to change where it looks for the dll?

Comment: Hmm, that almost sounds like it's loading an old dll rather than your newly built one, could it be loading it from the GAC? Maybe try running Fuslogvw to load the dll loading when you're debugging to make sure the dll is coming from the right place. Have you checked the project settings build tab to see if it's set to output the assembly somewhere weird?

Comment: I figured it out. I think the previous developers were the project referencing dlls by specific paths rather than actually referencing the project. The dll that it was loading was not the same dll that was being generated by the project

Comment: What a nasty error, just can't get around that!